# CSS style don't change despite react state change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have created the const isTransitionEnabled and isMenuToggled states. When the button is pressed, the isMenuToggled is set to true, and the style change. While isTransitionEnabled is default in false, and set to true before isMenuToggled is set, and once the isMenuToggled action is completed isTransitionEnabled is set to false again. The purpose is to prevent transition when the site is rerendered due to window size or orientation change etc.

I have try to write some async javascript code. However, the despite the state is changed, there is no effect on the style, and transition is disabled regardless of the isTransitionEnabled. Why?

Here are some code:

```
import React , { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive'
import './App.css'

import Header from './Header/Header'

export default function Home() {
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery({
        query: '(max-device-width: 1024px)'
    })

    const [isMenuToggled, SetIsMenuToggled] = useState(false)
    const [isTransitionEnabled, SetTransitionEnabled] = useState(false)




    const isMenuToggledReporter = async ()=> {

        const ToggleMenu = (TransitionState)=>{
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                //console.log(TransitionState)
                SetIsMenuToggled(!isMenuToggled)
                resolve(TransitionState)
            })
        }

        const ChangeTransitionState = (TransitionState)=>{
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                SetTransitionEnabled(!TransitionState)
                //console.log(TransitionState)
                resolve(!TransitionState)
            })
        }

        //ChangeTransitionState(isTransitionEnabled)
        //.then((TransitionState)=>{

            //return ToggleMenu(TransitionState)})
        //.then((TransitionState)=>{

            //ChangeTransitionState(TransitionState)
        //})

        const promise1 = await ChangeTransitionState(false)

        const promise2 = await ToggleMenu(promise1)

        const promise3 = await ChangeTransitionState(promise2)

        console.log(`promise 1 is ${promise1}`)
        console.log(`promise 2 is ${promise2}`)
        console.log(`promise 3 is ${promise3}`)

        //SetIsMenuToggled(!isMenuToggled)

        //SetTransitionEnabled(true)
    }

    //Use observer pattern for main div

    //If toggle, the menu is open, disable transition
    return (
        <div style={{
        }}>
            <div style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                right: isMenuToggled?'40vw':'0',
                height: '100vh',
                width: '100vw',
                display: 'grid',
                gridTemplateRows: 'repeat(20, 5vmax)',
                transition: isTransitionEnabled?'right 1s':'none'
            }}>
                <Header isMobile={isMobile} isMenuToggledReporter={isMenuToggledReporter} isTransitionEnabled={isTransitionEnabled}/>            
            </div>
            <div style={isMobile?{
                position: 'absolute',
                background: '#008b8b',
                left: isMenuToggled?'60vw':'100vw',
                height: '100vmax',
                width: '40vw',
                transition: isTransitionEnabled?'left 1s':'none',
            }:{
                display: 'none',
            }}>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```